# Google API Speeds Slow in Cloud Run / Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, serverless, google-cloud-run

**Bottom Line**: Cloud Run and Cloud Functions seem to have bizarrely limited bandwidth to the Google <s>Drive</s> API endpoints. Looking for advice on how to work around, or, ideally, @Google support to fix the underlying issue(s) as I will not be the only like use case.

**Background**: I have what I *think* is a really simple use case. We're trying to automate private domain Google Drive users to take existing audio recordings and send them off to Speech API to generate a transcript on an ad hoc basis, and to dump the transcript back into the same Drive folder with email notification to the submitter. Easy, right? Only hard part is that Speech API will only read from Google Cloud Storage, so the 'hard part' should be moving the file over. 'Hard' doesn't really cover it...

**Problem**: Writing in nodejs and using the latest version of the official modules for Drive and GCS, the file copying was going **extremely** slow. When we broke things down, it became apparent that the <s>GCS speed was acceptable (mostly -- honestly it didn't get a robust test, but was *fast enough* in limited testing); it was the Drive</s> ingress which was causing the real problem. Using even the sample [Google Drive Download app from the repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js) was slow as can be. Thinking the issue might be either my code or the library, though, I ran the same thing from the Cloud Console, and it was fast as lightning. Same with GCE. Same locally. But in Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, it's like molasses.

**Request**:

1. Has anyone in the community run into this or a like issue and found a workaround?
2. @Google -- Any chance that whatever the underlying performance bottleneck is, you can fix it? This is a quintessentially 'serverless' use case, and it's hard to believe that the folks who've been doing this the longest can't crack it.

Thank you all in advance!

**Updated 1/4/19** -- GCS is also slow following more robust testing. Image base also makes no difference (tried nodejs10-alpine, nodejs12-slim, nodejs12-alpine without impact), and memory limits equally do not impact results locally or on GCP (256m works fine locally; 2Gi fails in GCP).

Google Issue at: https://issuetracker.google.com/147139116

Answer (score 0):

Self-inflicted wound. Google-provided code seeks to be asynchronous and do work in the background. Cloud Run and Cloud Functions do not support that model (for now at least). Move to promise-chaining and all of a sudden it works like it should -- so long as the CPU keeps the attention it needs. Limits what we can do with CR / CF, but hopefully that too will evolve.

Comment: Facing same issue with python and not sure how to resolve it, could you help